# Angular Error Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode. mat selection multiple

Tags: angular, typescript

**Everthing working fine just given one error on console how to remove this error any one help me please Save, Edit searching working fine. **

```
public campaignCategoryFormGroup$: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    // 'categoryGroupId': [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [
    //  Validators.required
    // ]],
    'categoryId': [[], [Validators.required]],
    'subCategoryId': [[], [Validators.required]],
});

    public campaignCategoryForm: FormArray = this.fb.array([
    this.campaignCategoryFormGroup$
]);
<div class="col s4">
   <app-mat-select-search multiple (selectionChange)="onSelectCategory($event.value, true, false)"
   [label]="'CATEGORY_ID' | translate: lang" [list]="categoryList" valueField="categoryId"
   [myFormControl]="campaignService.campaignCategoryFormGroup$.controls['categoryId']"
   [requiredMsg]="'REQUIRED' | translate:lang"
   [searchPlaceholder]="'CATEGORY_SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate: lang" [isInactive]="true" [isRequired]="true"
   [noResultsLabel]="'CATEGORY_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND' | translate: lang" displayField="categoryName">
   </app-mat-select-search>
</div>
<div class="col s4">
   <app-mat-select-search multiple [label]="'SUB_CATEGORY_ID' | translate: lang" [list]="subCategoryList"
   valueField="subCategoryId"
   [myFormControl]="campaignService.campaignCategoryFormGroup$.controls['subCategoryId']"
   [requiredMsg]="'REQUIRED' | translate:lang"
   [searchPlaceholder]="'SUB_CATEGORY_GROUP_SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate: lang" [isInactive]="true"
   [isRequired]="true" [noResultsLabel]="'SUB_CATEGORY_GROUP_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND' | translate: lang"
   displayField="subCategoryName">
   </app-mat-select-search>
</div>
```

[image]

core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode.
Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode.

Comment: Again given same error any one know why this thing happening ?

Answer (score 0):

---

### multiple

```
<app-mat-select-search multiple [label]="'SUB_CATEGORY_ID' | translate: lang" [list]="subCategoryList">
```

---

### instead

---

### [multiple]="true"

```
<app-mat-select-search [multiple]="true" [label]="'SUB_CATEGORY_ID' | translate: lang" [list]="subCategoryList">
```